# By vs through prepositions

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, word-difference

In these two sentences–

> It is **through** advertisements that we are informed of new products and events.
>
> ...we are also reminded **by** advertisements to save for the future and spend wisely, subtly but just as often.

What's the difference between *by* and *through* in these sentences? Why can *by* not be used in the first one and *through* in the second?

Answer (score 1):

The two terms can overlap, but in your sentences they exhibit a difference.

*By* introduces an agent, and is especially common in the passive voice.

> We are reminded **by** advertisements...
>   
> → Advertisements remind us...

*Through* introduces an instrument.

> It is **through** advertisements that we are informed...
>   
> → Advertisements are how we are informed...

Technically, we don't have an explicit subject for this second case.

The difficulty comes in when you consider that *by* can also introduce an instrument. Often, this will be in the larger structure *by means of*. This expression is a synonym of *through* in the above sense.

> It is **by means of** advertisements that we are informed...
>   
> → Advertisements are how we are informed...

Answer (score 0):

*W did X through Y* - W controlled or convinced X to do Y indirectly - X was the thing or person that actually did something to Y.  W wanted X to happen.

*W did X by Y* - W controlled Y, and used it directly to make X happen.